# MongoDB: lookup into nested foreign field

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I have the following scenario:

A collection of `guests` who need to choose which bus stop they will take the bus from. Then I have the `buses`collection. Each bus have multiple trips, and each trip has multiple stops, and each stop has a location.

I need to make a mongo query which returns the guest info with the bus stop they chose (bus stop info + populated `location`).

The problem is that `trips`, `stops` and `location` are not mongo documents, but subdocuments from `buses`.

`guests` collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  ...
  bus_stop: ObjectId
  ...
}
```

`buses` collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  ...
  trips: [{ //<-- Subdocument
    _id: ObjectId
    stops: [{ //<-- Subdocument
      _id: ObjectId,
      time: Date,
      location: { //<-- Subdocument
        _id: ObjectId,
        ...
        name: String,
        coordinates: [Number]
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

What I need:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  ...
  bus_stop: {
    _id: ObjectId,
    time: Date,
    location: {
      _id: ObjectId,
      ...
      name: String,
      coordinates: [Number]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to perform a `$lookup`, but no luck so far. This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
$lookup: {
  from: "buses",
  let: { stop_id: "$bus_stop" },
  pipeline: [
    { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$$stop_id", "$going_trips.$stops._id" ] } } } // trying to filter out the bus containing the bus stop
    ... // more stuff should probably go here
  ],
  as: "bus_stop",
},
```

This is incomplete and wrong, but I'm stuck here on this step trying to filter out the buses which contains the bus stop in question. After this, I should probably figure out how to get the bus stop ans location info.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question can be better explained and understood with some actual json documents and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Z5Lp8QG4gY

```
db.guests.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "buses",
      let: {
        stop_id: "$bus_stop"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$trips"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$trips.stops"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$stop_id",
                "$trips.stops._id"
              ]
            },
            
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bus_stopDetails",
      
    }
  }
])
```

you could do something like this here i did first unwind the trips and stops then checked the stopID, you need to tweak this based on your need and this is working solution but i feel it can be optimized further by tuning query if needed.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great place to start, I can see my main problem was that I needed to first unwind  `$trips` and `$trips.stops`

Comment: pls keep in mind that there will be some performance degradation depending on data volume you have so pls run some load test with massive data to ensure your query is performing well